# Improving a binning algorithm without using arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm, montecarlo, binning

Premise: Algorithm **B** introduced below is the raw algorithm that stays behind a binning procedure in a Monte Carlo simulation.

I have an algorithm **A** that outputs, indipendently and in an ordered sequence (i.e, not contemporary), *n* generically different values for the same single variable; this means that if not stored anywhere, a single value is swept away by the next one. These values need to be processed by an algorithm **B**, which works in the following way:

1) Average over couples of contiguous values (i.e, the first with the second, the third with the fourth, and so on);
2) Determine the standard deviation of the newly obtained *n/2* values and store it away;
3) Set *n = n/2*;
4) Return to point (1) if *n > 1*.

I have successfully managed to implement algorithm **B** in c++ by storing the *n* initial values in a first array with *n* entries and the standard deviations in a second array of variable size; however, since I want *n* to be arbitrary large, it seems to me that this solution is not the best one.
Thus my question: is there any other way I can implement algorithm **B** without storing the *n* values in an array?

---

Edit: Here follows an example of how algorithm **B** works with the n-size array.

```
int n; //Number of values.
double * first_array = new double[n]; //Array in which every single value given by Algorithm A is stored.
do
{
  for (int x = 0; x < n/2; x++)  //As in point (1).
     first_array[x] = (first_array[2*x] + first_array[2*x + 1])/2.0;
  ... //Here I put the values in first_array in an appropriate function to obtain the standard deviation of this single set of values and store it away as in (2).
  n = n/2; //As in point (3).
 } while (n > 1); //As in point (4).
```

Comment: What is the value "n" in the last paragraph it seems like the number of entries but then in point #3 you are saying return to #1 if n > 1?  Also when you return to point #1 do you reset restart computing the standard deviation?  An example might help.

Comment: Thanks @tarkmeper, I omitted a fundamental point in the algorithm. I edited the question adding it, plus some code that I hope it will be useful.

Comment: This cries for FFT / wavelet transform; but if you want to do this manually, you can precalculate almost everything at each input in log2(n) time.
1. observe that there are log2(n) iterations; have a tmp var for each std. dev
2. find a good iterative algorithm for std. dev.
3. allocate an array of log(n) `double` values for the std devs, init. them, feed each value to them.

Comment: @lorro I think I got the point, thanks a lot! What about the FFT way instead? Could you expand a little on it?